# How To Loop and Load Section of JSON to New Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting some dynamic data from Ajax call in JSON format on

```
var out;
request.done(function( data ) {
                    out = data;
                    console.log(out);
 });
```

which looks like

```
{  
   "seq":"1",
   "node":"1407",
   "edge":"1721",
   "cost":"0.00155228618815934",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.339494 49.3269419000001,-124.3387254 49.3269805,-124.338669 49.3270201,-124.3386158 49.3270832000001,-124.3386343 49.3274121000001,-124.3386975 49.3274896,-124.3390742 49.3276439000001,-124.3394701 49.3277238000001,-124.339726 49.3277574000001,-124.3398638 49.3277496000001,-124.3399475 49.3277140000001,-124.3400263 49.3276270000001,-124.3402516 49.3272857000001,-124.340277 49.3271520000001,-124.3402715 49.3270367000001,-124.3402042 49.3269591000001,-124.3401021 49.3269305000001,-124.339494 49.3269419000001))"
}{  
   "seq":"2",
   "node":"2459",
   "edge":"43870",
   "cost":"0.0014795249102581",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.4051866 48.4191865000001,-123.4053714 48.4191387000001,-123.405405 48.4190178000001,-123.4050125 48.4186474000001,-123.4047663 48.4185377000001,-123.4045437 48.4185367000001,-123.4044758 48.4185937,-123.4043546 48.4189586000001,-123.404408 48.4190429000001,-123.4051866 48.4191865000001))"
}{  
   "seq":"3",
   "node":"14962",
   "edge":"15633",
   "cost":"0.00144452021471863",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.2005178 48.8657682,-124.2008549 48.8656748000001,-124.2011903 48.8656273,-124.2020436 48.8656722000001,-124.2029403 48.8658963,-124.2033335 48.8659029,-124.2034588 48.8658654000001,-124.2034906 48.8658182,-124.2034447 48.8657724,-124.203297 48.8657185000001,-124.203148 48.8656980000001,-124.2027598 48.865705,-124.20221 48.8655579000001,-124.2017332 48.8654932000001,-124.200973 48.8654362,-124.2006816 48.8654025000001,-124.200004 48.8651794,-124.1997069 48.8650816000001,-124.1995273 48.8650453000001,-124.1992556 48.8650290000001,-124.1988955 48.8649418000001,-124.1987556 48.8649332000001,-124.1986996 48.8649719000001,-124.1986801 48.8650336000001,-124.1986764 48.8650454,-124.1987314 48.8651373000001,-124.1988681 48.8651927000001,-124.1992515 48.8652406000001,-124.1995975 48.8653437,-124.2000068 48.8655325,-124.2005013 48.8657606,-124.2005178 48.8657682))"
}{  
   "seq":"4",
   "node":"13891",
   "edge":"13862",
   "cost":"0.00076542396749831",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.4606302 49.3438327000001,-124.4605727 49.3436995000001,-124.4604416 49.3435897000001,-124.4602789 49.3435198000001,-124.4601008 49.3434993000001,-124.4599664 49.3435289000001,-124.4598809 49.3436195,-124.4598941 49.3441714000001,-124.4599637 49.3442309000001,-124.4600623 49.3442440000001,-124.4601711 49.3441961,-124.4606302 49.3438327000001))"
}{  
   "seq":"5",
   "node":"3684",
   "edge":"28825",
   "cost":"0.00117904724673861",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.3495787 48.4045938,-123.3496211 48.4041484000001,-123.3493846 48.4033146,-123.3492248 48.4032068000001,-123.3490655 48.4031857000001,-123.3489141 48.4032153000001,-123.3486746 48.4033022,-123.3486286 48.4034498,-123.3494207 48.4043084,-123.3495787 48.4045938))"
}{  
   "seq":"6",
   "node":"12168",
   "edge":"11270",
   "cost":"0.00109953281896407",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.4652201 48.4475155000001,-123.4648358 48.4482124,-123.4650847 48.4482788,-123.4654424 48.4475732000001,-123.4652201 48.4475155000001))"
}
```

now I need to load the `"st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING` of each seq to arrays of arry like

```
var paths = [
 [  
  [-124.339494,49.3269419000001],
  [-124.3387254,49.3269805],
  [-124.338669,49.3270201],
  ...
 ], 
 [  
  [-123.4051866, 48.4191865000001],
  [-123.4053714, 48.4191387000001],
  [-123.405405, 48.4190178000001],
  ....
 ]
];
```

Comment: you must have tried something. No ?

Comment: Substring out the leading MULTILINE part and the ending )), and then it's a split on comma, then splitting each one of those by space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can strip out the "MULTILINE..." portion of your string, and then split that string on a comma to get each set of coordinates. From there, you can split on the space separating the coordinates, and coerce to a Number. Like so:

```js
var data = [{  
   "seq":"1",
   "node":"1407",
   "edge":"1721",
   "cost":"0.00155228618815934",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.339494 49.3269419000001,-124.3387254 49.3269805,-124.338669 49.3270201,-124.3386158 49.3270832000001,-124.3386343 49.3274121000001,-124.3386975 49.3274896,-124.3390742 49.3276439000001,-124.3394701 49.3277238000001,-124.339726 49.3277574000001,-124.3398638 49.3277496000001,-124.3399475 49.3277140000001,-124.3400263 49.3276270000001,-124.3402516 49.3272857000001,-124.340277 49.3271520000001,-124.3402715 49.3270367000001,-124.3402042 49.3269591000001,-124.3401021 49.3269305000001,-124.339494 49.3269419000001))"
},{  
   "seq":"2",
   "node":"2459",
   "edge":"43870",
   "cost":"0.0014795249102581",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.4051866 48.4191865000001,-123.4053714 48.4191387000001,-123.405405 48.4190178000001,-123.4050125 48.4186474000001,-123.4047663 48.4185377000001,-123.4045437 48.4185367000001,-123.4044758 48.4185937,-123.4043546 48.4189586000001,-123.404408 48.4190429000001,-123.4051866 48.4191865000001))"
},{  
   "seq":"3",
   "node":"14962",
   "edge":"15633",
   "cost":"0.00144452021471863",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.2005178 48.8657682,-124.2008549 48.8656748000001,-124.2011903 48.8656273,-124.2020436 48.8656722000001,-124.2029403 48.8658963,-124.2033335 48.8659029,-124.2034588 48.8658654000001,-124.2034906 48.8658182,-124.2034447 48.8657724,-124.203297 48.8657185000001,-124.203148 48.8656980000001,-124.2027598 48.865705,-124.20221 48.8655579000001,-124.2017332 48.8654932000001,-124.200973 48.8654362,-124.2006816 48.8654025000001,-124.200004 48.8651794,-124.1997069 48.8650816000001,-124.1995273 48.8650453000001,-124.1992556 48.8650290000001,-124.1988955 48.8649418000001,-124.1987556 48.8649332000001,-124.1986996 48.8649719000001,-124.1986801 48.8650336000001,-124.1986764 48.8650454,-124.1987314 48.8651373000001,-124.1988681 48.8651927000001,-124.1992515 48.8652406000001,-124.1995975 48.8653437,-124.2000068 48.8655325,-124.2005013 48.8657606,-124.2005178 48.8657682))"
},{  
   "seq":"4",
   "node":"13891",
   "edge":"13862",
   "cost":"0.00076542396749831",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.4606302 49.3438327000001,-124.4605727 49.3436995000001,-124.4604416 49.3435897000001,-124.4602789 49.3435198000001,-124.4601008 49.3434993000001,-124.4599664 49.3435289000001,-124.4598809 49.3436195,-124.4598941 49.3441714000001,-124.4599637 49.3442309000001,-124.4600623 49.3442440000001,-124.4601711 49.3441961,-124.4606302 49.3438327000001))"
},{  
   "seq":"5",
   "node":"3684",
   "edge":"28825",
   "cost":"0.00117904724673861",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.3495787 48.4045938,-123.3496211 48.4041484000001,-123.3493846 48.4033146,-123.3492248 48.4032068000001,-123.3490655 48.4031857000001,-123.3489141 48.4032153000001,-123.3486746 48.4033022,-123.3486286 48.4034498,-123.3494207 48.4043084,-123.3495787 48.4045938))"
},{  
   "seq":"6",
   "node":"12168",
   "edge":"11270",
   "cost":"0.00109953281896407",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.4652201 48.4475155000001,-123.4648358 48.4482124,-123.4650847 48.4482788,-123.4654424 48.4475732000001,-123.4652201 48.4475155000001))"
}];

var paths = data.map(elem => {
  var coordsBegin = elem.st_astext.split("((")[1];
  var coords = coordsBegin.split("))")[0];
  return coords.split(",").map(coord => coord.split(" ").map(Number));
});
console.log(paths);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the initial data structure is an array of objects, you can loop through it and generate the desired output with `Array.prototype.map`

```
const data = [{  
   "seq":"1",
   "node":"1407",
   "edge":"1721",
   "cost":"0.00155228618815934",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.339494 49.3269419000001,-124.3387254 49.3269805,-124.338669 49.3270201,-124.3386158 49.3270832000001,-124.3386343 49.3274121000001,-124.3386975 49.3274896,-124.3390742 49.3276439000001,-124.3394701 49.3277238000001,-124.339726 49.3277574000001,-124.3398638 49.3277496000001,-124.3399475 49.3277140000001,-124.3400263 49.3276270000001,-124.3402516 49.3272857000001,-124.340277 49.3271520000001,-124.3402715 49.3270367000001,-124.3402042 49.3269591000001,-124.3401021 49.3269305000001,-124.339494 49.3269419000001))"
}, {  
   "seq":"2",
   "node":"2459",
   "edge":"43870",
   "cost":"0.0014795249102581",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.4051866 48.4191865000001,-123.4053714 48.4191387000001,-123.405405 48.4190178000001,-123.4050125 48.4186474000001,-123.4047663 48.4185377000001,-123.4045437 48.4185367000001,-123.4044758 48.4185937,-123.4043546 48.4189586000001,-123.404408 48.4190429000001,-123.4051866 48.4191865000001))"
}, {  
   "seq":"3",
   "node":"14962",
   "edge":"15633",
   "cost":"0.00144452021471863",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.2005178 48.8657682,-124.2008549 48.8656748000001,-124.2011903 48.8656273,-124.2020436 48.8656722000001,-124.2029403 48.8658963,-124.2033335 48.8659029,-124.2034588 48.8658654000001,-124.2034906 48.8658182,-124.2034447 48.8657724,-124.203297 48.8657185000001,-124.203148 48.8656980000001,-124.2027598 48.865705,-124.20221 48.8655579000001,-124.2017332 48.8654932000001,-124.200973 48.8654362,-124.2006816 48.8654025000001,-124.200004 48.8651794,-124.1997069 48.8650816000001,-124.1995273 48.8650453000001,-124.1992556 48.8650290000001,-124.1988955 48.8649418000001,-124.1987556 48.8649332000001,-124.1986996 48.8649719000001,-124.1986801 48.8650336000001,-124.1986764 48.8650454,-124.1987314 48.8651373000001,-124.1988681 48.8651927000001,-124.1992515 48.8652406000001,-124.1995975 48.8653437,-124.2000068 48.8655325,-124.2005013 48.8657606,-124.2005178 48.8657682))"
}, {  
   "seq":"4",
   "node":"13891",
   "edge":"13862",
   "cost":"0.00076542396749831",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-124.4606302 49.3438327000001,-124.4605727 49.3436995000001,-124.4604416 49.3435897000001,-124.4602789 49.3435198000001,-124.4601008 49.3434993000001,-124.4599664 49.3435289000001,-124.4598809 49.3436195,-124.4598941 49.3441714000001,-124.4599637 49.3442309000001,-124.4600623 49.3442440000001,-124.4601711 49.3441961,-124.4606302 49.3438327000001))"
}, {  
   "seq":"5",
   "node":"3684",
   "edge":"28825",
   "cost":"0.00117904724673861",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.3495787 48.4045938,-123.3496211 48.4041484000001,-123.3493846 48.4033146,-123.3492248 48.4032068000001,-123.3490655 48.4031857000001,-123.3489141 48.4032153000001,-123.3486746 48.4033022,-123.3486286 48.4034498,-123.3494207 48.4043084,-123.3495787 48.4045938))"
}, {  
   "seq":"6",
   "node":"12168",
   "edge":"11270",
   "cost":"0.00109953281896407",
   "st_astext":"MULTILINESTRING((-123.4652201 48.4475155000001,-123.4648358 48.4482124,-123.4650847 48.4482788,-123.4654424 48.4475732000001,-123.4652201 48.4475155000001))"
}];

var paths = data.map(({st_astext}) => {

  const [ _ ,numsStr ] = st_astext.match(/\(\((.*)\)\)/);
  const arr = numsStr.split(',').map(pair => pair.split(' ').map(Number))

  return arr;

});

console.log(paths);
```